# variable changes value when posted php

Tags: php, variables, post

I am establishing a variable from a prior page like so:

```
$years = $_POST['years'];
```

the value of this is either 1 or 5.

Later I want to use this value to determine a different value that goes to a database via a form like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="years" value="<?php 
    if ($years == 1) {
        echo '10';
    }
    else if ($years == 5) {
        echo '50';
    }
    ?>" />
```

My problem is, when I submit the form, the value of the original variable "$years" is changing to new post value.

Should I be writing this another way?

Comment: You haven't explained why you wouldn't want to use the 'new post value'.  Are you trying to only keep the first posted value?  Or what?

Comment: You should probably store the original value $_SESSION, as that's the simplest way it will be preserved between invocations. Read more about that here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: Why not tell us what you are actually *trying to do* instead of just getting us to guess how to solve your problem. If `$_POST['years']` can be either 1 or 5,  why are you making it 10 or 50 later on?

Comment: I am trying to retain the $years value after the new form is posted. I need it to define an if statement later.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

One solution I can think is this:

```
$prevent_year = false;
$years        = $_POST['years'];
if(isset($_POST['prevent_years']) && $_POST['prevent_years'])
    $prevent_years = $_POST['prevent_years'];

<input type="hidden" name="years" value="<?=($years==1?10:($years==5?50:""))?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="years" value="<?=$prevent_years?>" />
```

And the input... why not

```
<input type="hidden" name="years" value="<?=($years==1?10:50)?>" />
```

I don´t know if I understand 100% the question... but I hope it helps you.

Comment: how does this prevent $years from being overwritten by the newest $_POST['years'] value ?

Comment: must it prevent the old value?? ummm ok!! I didn' t understand well... I am going to edit... one second ;p

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can go about doing this. I would recommend you seperate your code and remove the "echo" function and instead make a variable which holds the new value of your "years" variable.

```
<?php 

$years = $_POST['years'];

if ($years == 1) {
    $newYears = 10;
}
else if ($years == 5) {
    $newYears = 50;
}

echo<<<_END
     INPUT THE ADDITIONAL BEGINNING OF HTML FOR FORM HERE
_END;

echo <input type="hidden" name="years" value=$years>;
echo <input type="hidden" name="newYears" value=$newYears>;

echo<<<_END
    INPUT THE ADDITIONAL -END OF HTML FOR FORM HERE
_END;
?>
```

Comment: ignore that last comment, the input type is obviously hidden for a reason lol

Comment: how does this prevent $years from being overwritten by the newest $_POST['years'] value ?

Comment: when I do it like this, the value for $years is going away.

Comment: i don't think i understood your question. i'll re-edit my original reply

Comment: If you would like to carry over variables from one file to the next within your application, I would recommend looking into $_SESSION variables. they are global variables which you can set and will retain information until they are "destroyed" or "unset"

Answer (score 0):

Just add another hidden input to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="years" value="<?php 
if ($years == 1) {
    echo '10';
}
else if ($years == 5) {
    echo '50';
}
?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="years-orig" value="<?php echo $years; ?>">
```

on the form submission page you can access the data like so:

```
$_POST['years'];
$_POST['years-orig'];
```